# Get the size of large files in C returns size as 0

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I created below code in a Objective C program to get the size of a file in a directory and I must do it in C without using any Objective-C methods. This works fine and gives the correct size when checking it with small size files. But when it comes to large files (tested with 7GB file) this size variable returns the size of the file as 0. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
//filePath is a string parameter which takes the path of the file
    FILE *fp=nil;
    const char  *filePathInToChar = [filePath UTF8String];
    fp = fopen(filePathInToChar, "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `ftell` returns the current position in the filestream as `long int` which on a 32bit system has usually a maximum value of 2^31 - or 2GB in other words.

You can use `stat` (so you don't actually need to open and close the file):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat buf;
stat(filePathInToChar, &buf);
off_t size = buf.st_size;
```

`off_t` should be `long long` which is usually 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ftello()`. It returns an off_t, which resolves to `long long` under Darwin.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used it as,  
`off_t size = ftello(fp);` 
Still the value is zero no. Is this code that I have used is correct?

Comment: Check that `fp` isn't NULL. (And don't use `nil`; that's for Objective-C types.)

Comment: fp is no null. that is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

7GB -> 7516192768 byte

If `long` on your platform is only 32bit, the maximum value it is able to hold is 2^31 (since it's signed) -> 2147483648 -> 2GB. Even if you make it unsigned, you would only be able to represent up to 4GB. You need to use a larger type. `long long` may be supported by your compiler. Try it, it's 64bit and big enough to hold that value. You may also try `int64_t` in `<stdint.h>` and see if that's supported.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if `fp` is `NULL` after the `fopen()` call?

```
if (fp) {
    /* fseek() to SEEK_END and then ftell() to get position */
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong!\n");
}
```

Note that `nil` is not `NULL`. Use `NULL` for C pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Using seeking won't tell you the size of the file anyway. At best it tells you the number of characters in the file but more likely it returns you some information which makes it easy for the implementation to seek. If you want to know the size of the file you'll need to resort to something like stat() or some version encapsulated to make its use easier, e.g. from Boost's file system library.